# Remove drop shadow in nemo previews

Tags: css, nemo

I recently started using Nemo because Nautilus has gotten pretty terrible. I quite like it, but one thing is still bugging me: the shadow of the preview of every image and video file (see below).

I've been looking around in the `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps/nemo.css` file but couldn't figure out how to get rid of that shadow.

In Nautilus you get a border instead of a shadow, so surely *something* is different. I just can't figure out what.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I've found the .png file of the shadow [here](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/blob/master/icons/thumbnail_frame.png), on the Linux Mint github. No luck finding that file on my system though.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, you're out of luck unless you want to recompile it yourself. `nemo/icons/thumbnail_frame.png` is made with automake's "noinst_" prefix which means the image is not actually installed. Instead, what happens is the image data is compiled into the nemo binary.

If you really want to go the route of compiling your own binary (NOT TESTED, TRY AT YOUR OWN RISK):

1. First, remove `nemo/icons/thumbnail_frame.png` and also remove the reference to it in `nemo/icons/Makefile.am`
2. Install the prereq package `gnome-common`, which will give you `gnome-autogen.sh` needed for the next step.
3. Run `autogen.sh` (in the nemo-master directory). This will generate your configure script
4. Run `./configure` in this same directory. This will tell you if you're missing any packages (you'll be missing a lot of them and it will probably depend on some cinnamon packages which aren't in the default Ubuntu repos)
5. Run `make` in this directory. This should give you your nemo binary which you can then replace your old nemo with.

Good luck!

Comment: Where can I fine thumbnail_frame.png? It's not in /usr/share/nemo/icons and I don't know where else to look.

Comment: I mean in the Github repo you can download here https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/archive/master.zip

Comment: Ah yes of course, that was silly of me. All this seems like too much work for something I will probably get used to. Thanks for your help.